# Количество совпадений в столбце Series

Tags: python, pandas

подскажите, как посчитать количество совпадений в столбце?
например, есть таблица

```
df = pd.Series(['a|b', 'a', 'a|d', 'a|c|d', 'c|b|c', 'd|c', 'b|a'])
```

как в нём посчитать какие самые повторяющиеся пары значений? чтобы получилось, например
ac повторяется x раз
ab повторяется y раз
abc повторяется z раз и т.д

Comment: Вопрос -  'd|c'  и 'c|d'  это одно и то же вхождение или порядок имеет значение?  'a|b'  и 'b|a'  -  это 2 вхождения  'ab'  или 1 'ab'  и 1 'ba'?

Comment: Второй вопрос. вы говорите самые повторяющиеся ПАРЫ значений, и тут же указываете ТРОЙКУ значений abc. Считать и тройки? Или если юудут, то и 4-ки, 5-ки и т.д?

Comment: Зря вы тут упомянули Pandas/ думаю, он тут мало поможет ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для столбца датафрейма:

```
df['x'].value_counts(sort=False).to_dict()
```

для сериас:

```
df = pd.Series(['a|b', 'a', 'a', 'a|d', 'a|c|d', 'c|b|c', 'd|c', 'b|a'])
df.value_counts(sort=False).to_dict()
```

выдаст

```
 {'a': 2, 'a|d': 1, 'b|a': 1, 'a|c|d': 1, 'd|c': 1, 'a|b': 1, 'c|b|c': 1}
```

Второй вариант через groupby:

```
df.groupby(by=df).size()
```

выдаст

```
Out[20]: 
a        2
a|b      1
a|c|d    1
a|d      1
b|a      1
c|b|c    1
d|c      1
dtype: int64
```

Но можно получить тот же словарь:

```
df.groupby(by=df).size().to_dict()
```

Comment: не совсем то. с первого раза нормально не объяснил. нужно узнать как какие значения в паре чаще всего встречаются друг с другом. чтобы применив к таким значениям столбца a|b, a|c|b, a|c|d, a|b|e получалось ab - раза, ас - два раза. обращу внимание, что в ячейке значения изначально разделены '|'

Comment: @Alexandr ну тут много решений будет.
подправьте ваш основной вопрос  -  детализируйте.
Думаю, тогда задача привлечет большее количество людей.
А я сча подумаю над лобовым решением...